# Array Dynamic initialization

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there any way to *dynamically initialize* array size without using pointer for the array?

Any array of data type except for array of objects.

using `const` keyword does not actually work as it has to be initialized to some value already through code and not by user/client.

Code:

```
void input() {
   int size; 
   cout<<"Enter the value of Array size\t"; 
   cin>>size; 
   float *ad = new float[size]; 
   float *inad = new float[size]; 
   float *e = new float[size];
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `std::vector`?

Comment: Are you trying to allocate uninitialized memory for the objects?  i.e. like std::vector::reserve()?

Comment: Please be careful with your phrasing and spelling. Your are difficult to read.

Comment: for ref: here's the code: void input()
{ 
int size;
cout<<"Enter the value of Array size\t";
cin>>size;

float *ad = new float[size];
float *inad = new float[size];
float *e = new float[size];-------

Comment: @Jayant [Edit your question and add the code](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17804547/edit)

Comment: You should explain the motivation for your question, because what you want to achieve is most likely possible just not the way you imagined.

Comment: @Jayant what you are trying to do in the code is not clear. Can you add   the complete function/entire program if it is small?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is `std::vector` :

```
// For an array of int
std::vector<int> array( size );
```

And you can add element dynamically :

```
array.push_back( 1 ); // 1 is an example
```

And it is the same with a custom object :

```
class MyObject {};

std::vector<MyObject> array( number_of_object );
```

If you need a little documentation : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

---

As it is said in the standard *§ 8.3.4*, arrays can only be sized with a constant expression :

> [...]
>
> An array declaration has the form : **D1 [ constant-expression] attribute-specifier-seq**
>
> If the *constant-expression* is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard only permits arrays to be sized with a constant expression (However, some compiler's may offer it as a non-standard language extension)

You could use a std::vector instead:-

```
std::vector<int> array(arr_size);
```

Or you could dynamically-allocate memory manually:-

```
int *const array = new int[arr_size];
```

...

```
delete [] array;  // Remember to delete when you're done
```

P.S: Y don't you want to use pointers? Its rather easy with them.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not gramatically clear, but I think what you are asking for is, without pointers can you create dynamic containers. And given the tags, you want to use C++.

Thus

```
class Foo { 
// Default copy and move constructor created by compiler to allow fast copy by value
};

std::vector<Foo> my_dynamic_array;
```

If you want to reserve some space

```
my_dynamic_array.reserve(50);
```

If you want to add items to it by value, no pointers

```
Foo aFoo;
my_dynamic_array.push_back(aFoo);
```